# paypal linking payment to customers

Tags: paypal, callback, payment

I am just going to take the name and address of my customers and a link to the paypal standard form. The customers name, and some other details are going to be stored in a php/mysql form.

How do I link the paypal payment to the customer? Is there a callack or something I can use.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are done with getting Personal details,Billing details,Delivery details.

In PayPal they have two urls while integrating. One is SuccessURL and the other is FailureURL. If the transaction is success, it will be redirected to the SuccessURL which you have given, else it will navigate to failure URL.

Its up to you to decide your success & failure URL.